# Data not rendering on Bokeh choropleth chart (Python)

Tags: python, bokeh, interactive, choropleth

I am working with data in the following format (see table below) to plot an interactive Bokeh choropleth that allows me to 1) adjust the data source between two datasets (total_orders, total_revenue) and 2) implement two sliders for month and year.

```
<class 'geopandas.geodataframe.GeoDataFrame'>
Int64Index: 555 entries, 0 to 554
Data columns (total 7 columns):
 #   Column             Non-Null Count  Dtype   
---  ------             --------------  -----   
 0   year               555 non-null    int64   
 1   month              555 non-null    int64   
 2   geolocation_state  555 non-null    object  
 3   total_orders       555 non-null    int64   
 4   total_revenue      555 non-null    float64 
 5   geometry           555 non-null    geometry
 6   total_orders_log   555 non-null    float64 
dtypes: float64(2), geometry(1), int64(3), object(1)
memory usage: 50.9+ KB
```

The code that I am using thus far allows me to render the geometry but not the color shading I would expect. I've iterated on this a few time and thus far have failed every modification. Can anyone get a sense of what I might be missing here?

```
from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.models import GeoJSONDataSource, HoverTool, Select, Slider, LinearColorMapper, CustomJS
from bokeh.palettes import Spectral6
from bokeh.layouts import column, widgetbox
import json
import pandas as pd

# create a GeoJSONDataSource from the geometry column in your data
geo_source = GeoJSONDataSource(geojson=brazil_ecommerce.to_json())

# create a color mapper to map states to colors based on the data being shown
color_mapper = LinearColorMapper(palette=Spectral6, low=brazil_ecommerce.total_orders.min(), high=brazil_ecommerce.total_orders.max())

# create a figure and add a patch glyph to render the states
fig = figure(title='Brazil E-commerce', plot_width=800, plot_height=500)
states = fig.patches('xs', 'ys', source=geo_source, fill_color={'field': 'data', 'transform': color_mapper}, line_color='black', line_width=0.5)

# create a hover tool to show information about the states
hover = HoverTool(tooltips=[('State', '@geolocation_state'), ('Data', '@data')], renderers=[states])
fig.add_tools(hover)

# create a select tool to switch between total_orders and total_revenue
select = Select(title='Data', value='total_orders', options=['total_orders', 'total_revenue'])

# create a year slider to control the year
year_slider = Slider(title='Year', start=int(brazil_ecommerce['year'].min()), end=int(brazil_ecommerce['year'].max()), step=1, value=int(brazil_ecommerce['year'].min()))

# create a month slider to control the month
month_slider = Slider(title='Month', start=int(brazil_ecommerce['month'].min()), end=int(brazil_ecommerce['month'].max()), step=1, value=int(brazil_ecommerce['month'].min()))


brazil_ecommerce_dict = json.loads(geojson_data)


# create a CustomJS callback to update the data shown on the map
callback = CustomJS(args=dict(geo_source=geo_source, select=select, year_slider=year_slider, month_slider=month_slider, color_mapper=color_mapper, brazil_ecommerce=brazil_ecommerce_dict), code="""
    const new_data = {
        'geolocation_state': [],
        'xs': [],
        'ys': [],
        'data': []
    }
    const selected_data = select.value;
    const selected_month = month_slider.value;
    const selected_year = year_slider.value;
    for (var i = 0; i < brazil_ecommerce['year_month'].length; i++) {
        if (brazil_ecommerce['year_month'][i] == selected_month) {
            new_data['geolocation_state'].push(brazil_ecommerce['geolocation_state'][i]);
            new_data['xs'].push(brazil_ecommerce['xs'][i]);
            new_data['ys'].push(brazil_ecommerce['ys'][i]);
            new_data['data'].push(brazil_ecommerce[selected_data][i]);
        }
    }
    geo_source.geojson = JSON.stringify(new_data);
    if (selected_data == 'total_orders') {
        color_mapper.low = brazil_ecommerce.total_orders.min();
        color_mapper.high = brazil_ecommerce.total_orders.max();
    } else {
        color_mapper.low = brazil_ecommerce.total_revenue.min();
        color_mapper.high = brazil_ecommerce.total_revenue.max();
    }
""")

# add the callback to the select tool and slider
select.js_on_change('value', callback)
year_slider.js_on_change('value', callback)
month_slider.js_on_change('value', callback)

# create a layout with the map and the controls
layout = column(fig, widgetbox(select, year_slider, month_slider))

# show the output in the notebook
output_notebook()
show(layout)
```

Welcome any support!